# Cleanup huge Perl Codebase

Tags: perl, web-applications, cgi, code-cleanup

I am currently working on a roughly 15 years old web application.

It contains mainly **CGI** perl scripts with **HTML::Template** templates.

It has over 12 000 files and roughly 260 MB of total code. I estimate that no more than 1500 perl scripts are needed and I want to get rid of all the unused code.

There are practically no tests written for the code.

My questions are:

- Are you aware of any **CPAN module** that can help me get a list of only `use`d and `require`d modules?
- What would be your approach if you'd want to get rid of all the extra code?

I was thinking at the following approaches:

- try to override the `use` and `require` perl builtins with ones that output the loaded file name in a specific location
- override the `warnings` and/or `strict` modules `import` function and output the file name in the specific location
- study the `Devel::Cover` perl module and take the same approach and analyze the code when doing manual testing instead of automated tests
- replace the perl executable with a custom one, which will log each name of file it reads (I don't know how to do that yet)
- some creative use of [`lsof`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_lsof.htm) (?!?)

Comment: My approach would be to start with writing the tests before touching any code, just like always when doing major maintenance.

Comment: My estimations are that 80% of the code is not used/needed - it is not  financially feasible to write tests for the whole code.

Comment: @TudorConstantin - don't write unit tests for the CODE. Write functional tests for use cases of the app.

Comment: @TudorConstantin - when you have 100% use cases covered, you can even use that to get the code call graphs etc... from `Devel::Cover`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Devel::Modlist](http://p3rl.org/Devel%3a%3aModlist) may give you what you need, but I have never used it.

The few times I have needed to do somehing like this I have opted for the more brute force approach of inspecting `%INC` at the end the program.

```
END {
    open my $log_fh, ...;
    print $log_fh "$_\n" for sort keys %INC;
}
```

Comment: there is more than one way to do it - your both ways seems just right for my need. Right now I am working on the `END{...}` approach and it works smoothly - big thank you

Answer (score 2):

As a first approximation, I would simply run

```
egrep -r '\<(use|require)\>' /path/to/source/*
```

Then spend a couple of days cleaning up the output from that. That will give you a list of all of the modules used or required.

You might also be able to play around with `@INC` to exclude certain library paths.

If you're trying to determine execution path, you might be able to run the code through the debugger with 'trace' (i.e. 't' in the debugger) turned on, then redirect the output to a text file for further analysis. I know that this is difficult when running CGI...

Comment: this will output all the modules in the codebase as being used/needed, because there are older versions of the application that have been rewritten (copy/paste then rewrite). I know some entry points for the application, maybe if I build a graph for those dependencies and extract all the files that are related to the entry points.....

Comment: Ahh. So you have 12000 source files, but you don't know which ones are or are not being executed?

Comment: You should be able to determine your entry points from your web server logs. You might then consider writing a short spider to read each file in the list, and search for the use and require statements. Record each newly discovered file in some scoreboard or graph, and the put it on the list, and continue until the list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the relevant timestamps are turned on, you could check access times on the various script files - that should rule out any top-level script files that aren't being used.

Might be worth adding some instrumentation to CGI.pm to log the current script-name ($0) to see what's happening.

Comment: thank you for your answer - worth investigating - especially for non perl resources like images